# Displaying encoded image with foreach always show the last one

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, foreach

I got an issue that i don't uderstand, I'm trying to display images stored in an oracle database with a foreach. I succeed do display the images one by one using this                     `echo '<img class="col-md-2 img-thumbnail" src="data:'.$value['IMGTYPE'].';base64,'.$value['IMAGE'].'"/>';` but when I try to display all of them in a foreach loop, well it only shows the last one.
I checked the data in the foreach and they are different and corresponding at what expected.

To display the images I begin to select it in the db and encode it, creating the array that I will be displaying:

```
$imgTab= $this->imgManager->SelectImages($this->session->IDUtil);
foreach($imgTab as $key => $img)
    $imgTab[$key]["IMAGE"]= encodeFlobImage($img["IMAGE"]);

function encodeFlobImage($img)
{
    return base64_encode(stream_get_contents($img));
}

foreach($imgTab as $value)
   echo '<img class="col-md-2 img-thumbnail" src="data:'.$value['IMGTYPE'].';base64,'.$value['IMAGE'].'"/>';
```

**EDIT**

Here is the select function:

```
public function SelectImgProfil($idUtil)
{
    $stmt = $this->Connect->prepare("SELECT image, imgType FROM ".$this->Table." WHERE IDUTIL = :idUtil AND PROFIL= 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(':idUtil' => $idUtil));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!$row)
        return array('IMAGE' => fopen(asset_url("images/anonymous.gif"), 'rb'), 'IMGTYPE' => 'image/gif');
    else
        return $row;
}
```

print_r of $imgTab
[image: print_r of $imgTab]

I hope you got the mater, if you need more information just ask. Sorry for my bad english wich lacks of practise.

Comment: view page source, is the html correct?

Comment: Yes the images are displaying properly, the only issue is that it always show the last picture added

Comment: @RemiHirtz : can you please put the output of `$imgTab` using `print_r($imgTab)` because I think as you are adding key so it will associative array and so you need to make two `foreach` loop for printing images.

Comment: I put it as a picture in the post because it was too long to copy/paste it

Comment: But I have the fealing that the problem is not here, I think that it's in the encoding part. Because when I display the array afterward the image type are different, but the raw image are the same.